# Is it possible to only use your Google account for Google Play only?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, logging

I'm developing Android applications on a phone (5.0.2) provided by my company so I'm supposed to log on Google Play in order to download other applications and test them.

The thing is with that, all of my Gmail, Drive, Photos, Hangouts, Youtube, Keep (and the list goes on) are automatically synchronized and made available with a simple "login button"... Which is quite embarrassing.

Everytime I try to log out from any of those google services, it redirects me to Android's parameters accounts tab... like it's all or nothing.

**So the question is : How can I login to Google Play alone ?**
Thanks

Comment: "Which is quite embarrassing." - are you suggesting you are using a personal Google account "on a phone provided by [your] company"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to "Settings>Applications>Google" you can turn off automatic syncing to the device. For the login button there's two things you can do:

1. I think you can deauthenticate the device from your google settings.
2. Simply solove the problem by creating another account you use just to do work-stuff. You shouldn't mix private and business life.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's what I did, I disabled the automatic syncing for all the Google applications. Thanks